# N2 CMS Setup problem, missing an assembly reference <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>

Tags: .net, n2

I'm trying to use N2 CMS. I've download the Template MVC version. I've followed the steps in the installation text. When I run it I get:

The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Has anybody else had this problem?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the MVC futures assembly and put it in the bin folder

it can be found here

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742